# Error: While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree`

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, updates, react-native

i have upgraded my react native package from `0.51.0` to `0.56.0` and when i try to build my project with `npm start` i get this error `Error: While resolving module react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree`.
The error is telling that the `ReactNativeComponentTree.js` is not found in the `react-native` folder. 
I took a look at the react-native source code and i found that the file is deleted in the `0.56.0` version and nothing was mentioned in the documentation or in the changelog.
the file was used (the code is not mine) to get the placeholder of a selected input (on focus) with the following code.
`import ReactNativeComponentTree from "react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree";`

---

```
handler = e => {  
    let { placeholder } = ReactNativeComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(
      e.nativeEvent.target
    ).memoizedProps;

//the use of {placeholder} here
}
```

Anyone knows what to do to resolve this issue ? or is there a better way to get the placeholder of a selected input , without the use of the **ReactNativeComponentTree.js** file ?